# All the Javascript functions for my web page suddenly stopped being recognized

Tags: javascript, dom-events

All of the buttons on my web site suddenly stopped working. When I try to press them, in the console it says that they don't exist. I've checked to make sure the Javascript filename in the script tag is correct. I made a folder only for my current Javascript, html, and CSS files. I tried changing the script tag from being at the end of the html document to in the header. None of these things did anything.

> medAppFreshStart3.html:33 Uncaught TypeError: noteModal is not a function
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (medAppFreshStart3.html:33)
> onclick @ medAppFreshStart3.html:33

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<header>
    <script src="medAppFreshStart3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="medAppStyle3.css" />
  </header>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d1">
        demographics
        <button onclick="newPatient()" id="newPatient">+ New Patient</button>
        <button onclick="localStorage.clear()" id="clearPtData">
          Clear Patient Data</button
        ><br />
        <!--<label for="search">Patient Search</label>-->
        <input id="search" placeholder="Enter patient name" />

        <button id="searchButton">search</button>

        <p id="nameDisplay"></p>
        <p id="ageDisplay"></p>

        <!--<label for="search">patient search</label>
        <input
          type="search"
          onsearch="findPatient()"
          name="search"
          id="search"
        />-->
      </div>
      <div class="d2 flex-container">
        current note
        <button onclick="noteModal()" id="newNote">+ Add</button>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="current-note-sub content-1" id="subjective">
            Subjective:
          </div>
          <div class="current-note-sub content-1" id="objective">
            Objective:
          </div>
          <div class="current-note-sub content-1" id="assessment">
            Assessment:
          </div>
          <div class="current-note-sub content-1" id="plan">Plan</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d3">
        Problem-list
        <button onclick="addProblem()" id="new problem">+ Add</button>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="problem">Problem:</div>
          <div class="problem">Problem:</div>
          <div class="problem">Problem:</div>
          <div class="problem">PRoblem:</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d4 flex-container">
        prescriptions
        <button onclick="addPrescription()" id="new prescription">+ Add</button>
        <div class="content" id="prescriptions">
          <div class="prescription" id="prescription1">prescription1</div>
          <div class="prescription" id="prescription2">prescription2</div>
          <div class="prescription" id="prescription3">prescription3</div>
          <div class="prescription" id="prescription4">prescription3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d5 flex-container">
        Previous Notes
        <div class="content">
          <div class="past-note" id="past-note1">Date: Complaint:</div>
          <div class="past-note" id="past-note2">Date: Complaint:</div>
          <div class="past-note" id="past-note3">Date: Complaint:</div>
          <div class="past-note" id="past-note4">Date: Complaint:</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addPrescription" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="closePrescription()" class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="post" id="prescriptionForm">
          <label for="Drug"> Drug:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="Drug"
            name="Drug"
            type="text"
            reqired
            aria-required="true"
          />

          <label for="Dosage"> Dosage:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="Dosage"
            name="Dosage"
            required
            aria-required="true"
          />
          <label for="measurement">Measurement</label>
          <select id="measurement" name="measurement">
            <option value="micrograms">micrograms</option>
            <option value="milligrams">milligrams</option>
            <option value="grams">grams</option>
          </select>
        </form>

        <button
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          form="PrescriptionForm"
          onclick="createPrescription(); closePrescription()"
        >
          + Create
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="noteModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="closeNote()" class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="post" id="noteForm" name="noteform">
          <label for="Date"> Date: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="Date"
            name="Date"
            reqired
            aria-required="true"
          />
          <label for="complaint"> Complaint: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="complaint"
            name="complaint"
            reqired
            aria-required="true"
          />
          <label for="subjective">Subjective</label>
          <textarea id="subjective" name="subjective"></textarea>
          <label for="objective">Objective</label>
          <textarea id="objective" name="objective"></textarea>
          <label for="assessment">Assessment</label>
          <textarea id="assesment" name="assessment"></textarea>
          <label for="plan">Plan</label>
          <textarea id="plan" name="plan"></textarea>
        </form>

        <button onclick="createNote(), closeNote()">+ Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addProblem" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="closeProblem()" class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="post" id="problemForm">
          <label for="problem"> Problem:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="problemForm"
            name="problemForm"
            reqired
            aria-required="true"
          />
        </form>

        <button
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          form="problem"
          onclick="closeProblem()"
        >
          + Create
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="newPtDemographics" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="closeDemo()" class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="post" id="demoForm">
          <label for="name"> Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            reqired
            aria-required="true"
          />

          <label for="age"> Age:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="age"
            name="age"
            reqired
            aria-required="true"
          />
        </form>

        <button onclick="createPatient(), closeDemo()">+ Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```
```function newPatient() {
  const addPatient = document.getElementById('newPtDemographics');
  addPatient.style.display = 'block';
}

function findPatient() {
  let name = document.getElementById(search);
  name = name.innerText;
  console.log(name);
}

const button1 = document.getElementById('searchButton');
searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const name = document.getElementById('search').value;
  //console.log(name);
  let patients = localStorage.getItem('patients');
  patients = JSON.parse(patients);
  let patient = patients[name];
  nameDisplay = document.getElementById('nameDisplay');
  ageDisplay = document.getElementById('ageDisplay');

  nameDisplay.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + patient[key];
  ageDisplay.innerHTML = 'Age' = patient.age;

  //console.log(patient);
  //patients = JSON.parse(patients);
});
function createPatient() {
  let patients = localStorage.getItem('patients');
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  if (patients !== null) {
    //instead of parsing here can just append array with new patient if it already exists.
    //Will need to parse to retrieve data to fill patient details when select new patient or
    //reopen broswer.
    patients = JSON.parse(patients);
  } else {
    patients = {};
  }
  patients[name] = { age: age };
  //patients.push({ [name]: { age: age } });
  localStorage.setItem('patients', JSON.stringify(patients));
  //console.log(patients[name]);
}
function addPrescription() {
  const addPrescription = document.getElementById('addPrescription');
  addPrescription.style.display = 'block';
}

function createPrescription() {
  const div = document.getElementById('prescriptions');

  const newPrescription = document.createElement('div');
  newPrescription.classList.add('prescription');
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  console.log(name);
  //var patient = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('patients.[name]'));
  //newPrescription.innerHTML = patient;
  //div.appendChild(newPrescription);
  //console.log('testing');
  //console.log(patient);
  //console.log('testing');
  /*
  newPrescription.innerHTML =
    'Drug: ' +
    document.getElementById('prescriptionForm').Drug.value +
    ' Dosage: ' +
    document.getElementById('prescriptionForm').Dosage.value +
    ' ' +
    document.getElementById('prescriptionForm').measurement.value;
  div.appendChild(newPrescription);
  */
}
function createNote() {
  let noteForm = document.getElementById('noteForm');
  let formData = new FormData(noteForm);
  var object = {};
  formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
    object[key] = value;
  });
  var note = JSON.stringify(object);
}
function noteModal() {
  const noteModal = document.getElementById('noteModal');
  noteModal.style.display = 'block';
}
function addProblem() {
  const addProblem = document.getElementById('addProblem');
  addProblem.style.display = 'block';
}
function closeProblem() {
  const addProblem = document.getElementById('addProblem');
  addProblem.style.display = 'none';
}
function closeNote() {
  const noteModal = document.getElementById('noteModal');
  noteModal.style.display = 'none';
}

function closePrescription() {
  const addPrescription = document.getElementById('addPrescription');
  addPrescription.style.display = 'none';
}
function closeDemo() {
  const addPatient = document.getElementById('newPtDemographics');
  addPatient.style.display = 'none';
}
````

Comment: Not the problem but you probably meant `<head>` instead of `<header>`.

Comment: An object with an ID becomes a global variable. Your `<div id="noteModal"` is creating a global variable `noteModal` pointing to the DIV; that seems to be overriding your global function. That's not supposed to happen, but it does seem like your `noteModal` reference is not a function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables What have you changed recently? Lastly, this is way too much code to post in a question. You need to post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `<header>` **must** be `<head>` in that place, as `<html>` can only have two children `<head>` and `<body>`.

Comment: It turned out to be some kind of simple syntax error I had made I found using the developer tools. Thanks for the info about ids creating global variables though, that's been good to know. I'm still not sure what's meant by overriding the global function though.